# UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for Primary key with Foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, unique-constraint

I am designing bookstore database and can't decide what relationship better. One book has many chapters and on front-end i have to know order of chapter in the book like this

BookName:

- Chapter-1
- Chapter-2

My tables:

**Book**

- PK  bookID
- pfK langID

**Chapter**

- PK chapterID
- FK bookID

Q: Can I add UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for (chapterID, bookID)

if not, can I solve it like this (but, I think it violates 3rd NORMAL FORM)

**Chapter**

- PK chapterID
- FK bookID
- chapterOrder

and add constraint for (bookID, chapterOrder)

My first solution with composite keys
**Chapter**

- PK chapterID
- PFK bookID
- PFK langID

I gave up on this, because with tables primary keys will increase, or is the first solution the best?

Comment: The primary key is always unique, so there's no need for a unique constraint on any combination of columns that includes `chapterID`

Comment: What does PFK mean?

Comment: Your second solution with `chapterOrder` is correct. You shouldn't have `langID` in `Chapter`, unless a book can have chapters in different languages.

Comment: thanks a lot, can it violate 3rd normal form? PFK - primary foreign key

Comment: Adding `langID` to the `Chapter` table violates 3NF. That just belongs in the `Book` table.

Comment: I understand, yes my book can't have diff languages

Comment: @Barmar can you add your comment as an answer, then I can check that question answered?

Comment: You already have the solution in the question.